# Hands ProcessBuilder In java Multi thread in Unix OS

Tags: java, multithreading, unix

Using unix OS, I am trying to run .sh file using ProcessBuilder in java Multi threading (.sh file is common, but arguments different for each thread). the code follows.

```
public class CLMScriptExe2 implements Runnable {
    final String scriptFileName = "/apps/orangd1/temp/CLM/CLM_PCF_Jenkins.sh";
    private String AppName;

    public CLMScriptExe2(String appName) {
          AppName = appName;
    }

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        try  {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(scriptFileName, AppName);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //String line;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            try  {
                process.waitFor();
            }  catch (InterruptedException e)  {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("ending executeScript--Testing");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            CLMScriptExe2 c1 = new CLMScriptExe2("appOne");
            Thread t1 = new Thread(c1);
            t1.start();

            CLMScriptExe2 c2 = new CLMScriptExe2("appTwo");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(c2);
            t2.start();

            CLMScriptExe2 c3 = new CLMScriptExe2("appThree");
            Thread t3 = new Thread(c3);
            t2.start();
    }
}
```

the Java program is terminating after **processBuilder.start()**.

Edited:
after this **processBuilder.start()**, No logs, No errors, No Exception, nothing, it just terminated for all threads.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What do you mean "terminating"? The JVM dies? No error? No logs? No other threads that continue to run? It doesn't print the "ProcessBuilder Started" line? Are you sure it's terminating and not just stopped?

Comment: after this processBuilder.start(), No logs, No errors, No Exception, nothing, it just terminated for all threads

Comment: In that case, please invest some time in creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and posting it in your question, so that we can all try to reproduce it on our machines.

Comment: Check your sh script. Does it start and finish successfully when you run it from command line?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there are no logs or exceptions? Your code as it stands will throw an `IllegalThreadStateException` as you're trying to start `t2` twice.  I've tried your code with various combinations of shell scripts that exist / don't exist / not executable and every single run produces output

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but maybe this will help someone else.
You are starting 3 threads but you aren't closing any ie you are missing:

```
 t1.join();
```

etc
I suspect you are getting a ConcurrentModificationException error.